# Add calculation formula to a existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a Detailed Bill Table in SQL Server, but the Total Price column is not automatically calculated. How can I update the formula for the column?
The formula is `Total=price*quantity*(1-Discount)`.

The info I added to the Detailed Bill table are:

```
insert into Detailed_Bill (BillID, ProductID, Price, Quantity, Discount, TotalPrice)
values
('03', '003', '0','3', '0.02', '0'),
('03', '007', '0','2', '0.01', '0'),
('03', '011', '0','10', '0', '0'),
('02', '010', '0','11', '0.04', '0'),
('02', '002', '0','2', '0.01', '0'),
('01', '004', '0','1', '0.05', '0'),
('01', '009', '0','15', '0.04', '0');
```

I tried the update code as

```
 update Detailed_Bill
set TotalPrice = price*quantity*(1-Discount);
```

But it didn't show the total price, just showed the '0' value. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: your price is 0 so any number multiplied by 0 is 0

Comment: I don't get it.  Can you show us what you want the table to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Create `totalPrice` as a calculated column:

```
alter table Detailed_Bill add TotalPrice as
    (price*quantity*(1-Discount));
```

This is then calculated when you *use* the value, so it is always up-to-date.  You do not insert the value in the insert.  So:

```
insert into Detailed_Bill (BillID, ProductID, Price, Quantity, Discount)
    values . . .
```